# Why does iloc use [] and not ()?

Tags: python, pandas

I am relatively new to python and it seems to me (probably because I don't understand) that the syntax is sometimes slightly inconsistent.

Suppose we are working with the pandas package `import pandas as pd`. Then any method within this package can be accessed by `pd.method`, i.e. `pd.DataFrame(...)`. Now, there are certain objects within the pandas package that have certain methods, i.e. `df.reindex()` (notice circular brackets), or certain attributes, i.e. `df.columns` (notice no brackets).

My question is two fold:

First of all, is what I have said above correct?

Secondly, why does the `iloc` method not maintain the above syntax? If it is a method then surely I should use `df.iloc(0,0)` instead of `df.iloc[0,0]` to obtain the top left value of a data frame...

Thanks

Comment: Because it's indexing, so they use the same syntax as e.g. indexing into a list.

Comment: Anything that is callable, uses () to call (i.e. a method or function).
Anything that is indexable, uses [] to index (i.e a list/array/collection etc.)

Comment: @BlueRine S but the callable `df.iloc` is also sliceable is what OP doesn’t understand

Comment: @Jab then you should explain to OP a bit more about the underlying core of OOP. maybe show an example with magic methods.

Comment: @jonrsharpe but then wouldn't it make more sense to type `df.iloc([0,0])`. In my head, if it is a method I should always need ()...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are conceptually correct, if it is a callable it should call with `()` instead of `[]` regardless whether it's sliceable or not. And that is exactly what happens under the hood. An example would be:

```
>>> lst = [1,2,3,4]
# slicing:
>>> lst[1:3]
... [2, 3]
# calling magic __getitem__ :
>>> lst.__getitem__(slice(1,3))
... [2, 3]
```

So, under the hood, slicing in any sliceable object works with this dunder-getitem method or something like that. However, this `__` concept, traditionally in OOP means `protected` that is you are strongly discouraged to call them directly, hence we do not see the method call itself, but an alias of some sort that is `[...]`. Also these `dunder` methods or `magic` would be very cumbersome in day-to-day programming, instead something like `[...]` or simply `+` (which is also a `magic` named `__add__`) are much easier to type, intuitive, and blend in well with the rest of the framework. Hence `.iloc` is used with `[...]` instead of a method call.

If you have time, I would like to refer you to pandas source code on `indexing`, try to find `_LocationIndexer`: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/indexing.py

Answer (score 4):

`import pandas as pd` here it is python module

`pd.DataFrame(...)` if you pay attention to naming convection `DataFrame` is a class here.

`df.reindex()` is a method called on instance itself.

`df.columns` has no bracket because it is an attribute of the object not a method

`df.iloc` is meant to get item by **index** so to show it's index-able nature `[]` makes more sense here.